# In Octave, how to compile a mex file from multiple C/C++ source files?

Tags: matlab, octave, mex

In Matlab, we can use `mex` to compile a library from multiple files (e.g., 100+ .c files) using something like

```
mex *.c -o mylib.mex
```

But in Octave, it seems like that only one input source file accepted, it always gives an error

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: *.c: Invalid argument
```

Tried googing a lot and find no solution. Any pointer to getting this problem solved will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you have 100+ source files and no build system? I'd expect such a large project to have a build system (i.e. you don't type a compile command manually, but type just `make` or press a button in an IDE or something).

Comment: [Looking at the sources](https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/8af86942ab2a2a3df08d02347cba3bf2cfa14bf6/src/mkoctfile.in.cc#L761), it looks like the function should accept multiple source files, my guess is that your command fails because it doesn't decode the wildcards. You could list all your source files explicitly. But more convenient would be to use a build system. Most of your .c files would form one or more libraries, which you then link into your MEX-file.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that Octave doesn't expand the wildcard, so it doesn't recognize `*.c` as a valid file name.

You could explicitly list all the source files like this:

```matlab
files = dir('*.c');
files = {files.name};
mex(files{:}, '-o', 'mylib.mex')
```

Comment: Cris, thanks a lot for your timely input. That was actually what I figured it out right before reading your post.  Glad that you are also thinking of the same thing. It took me almost 2 hrs to figure it out ( https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast/blob/4ec01e44c89a754ce1671879e440a9cc509cab54/Matlab/rbeast_mex_compile.m#L187C3-L187C3). Really amazed at your quick turnaround. Appreciate your generosity to help out here.

Comment: My project is in C but need to be delivered to users as a dll/mex/so/pyd in Python, R, and Maltab/Ocatave ( https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast : I exaggerated in the question post; so far, there are 60+ C files; eventually there will be more). I used a sloppy build system on my end, but I also try to let users (most are non-experts who have no idea about C and make) create a mex library on their own computer wthin Matlab/Ocatve itself.   Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @zhaokg I would use the same procedure you use on Octave for MATLAB as well. Using `*.c` in a compile command is more error prone, you never know what the user does to a source directory. Given that  you have a list of files hard-coded already, I would prefer using that list over a wildcard.

Comment: Cris, really appreciate your insights. You are absolutely right regarding the use of "*.c".  What you mentioned actually already happened (https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast/issues/13#issuecomment-1630954245). I will definitely follow your advice. Thanks a lot again.